# Microsoft Excel formula to detect word or number

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

How do I get a cell to determine if a word or a number is entered into it and then give a different numeric value for each entry?

Example:

`A1` has `ABCD 1234`
`A2` has `1234`
`A3` Needs to add them together BUT give a `.5` numeric value when letters are entered and a `1` numeric value if there are ONLY numbers entered.

Comment: OK it is clear I did not initially understand the question, since it has been reformatted. But I must confess I am a little more confused now. What am I adding together? So as your data above stands should A3 be 1.5? (because that would be harder without using additional columns.  Of course using my answer in column b, then summing them at the bottom would be workable solution).  If you can provide more info I can possible amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have correctly understood you, this should do the job for you:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(<cell reference>), 1,0.5)
```

Replacing <cell reference> with the cell to be checked.  So assuming you have this "abc 123" in cell A1:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1), 1,0.5)
```

The output will be 0.5 (in the cell you put the formula in)

And this "1234" in cell a2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2), 1,0.5)
```

The output is 1 in the (in the cell you put the formula in)

Break down of the formula:
=IF checks if the first item in the brackets is true or not, then for true returns the item after the 1st comma, if it is false, returns the item after the second comma. If you wish to change it to text simply wrap it in " (e.g. "Hello").
ISNUMBER() checks if the contents of  is a number or not, returns true or false.

Let me know if you have questions.